# Function to validate a GUID, an EntityState, and some data

Tags: c#, validation

In the beginning of my methods that handle the calls from outside, I run this method to make sure that everything's OK, or let the caller know what's wrong:

```
private static void Validate(Guid userId, EntityState state, object data)
{
  if (userId == Guid.Empty)
    throw new Exception("Token unrecognized!");
  if (state == EntityState.Detached)
    throw new Exception("Action unrecognized!");
  if (data == null)
    throw new Exception("Data unrecognized!");
}
```

I was happy with the method until R# remarked that I'm declaring the variables without using them, except for pre-condition check. Well, it's true that I do. It's kind of the whole idea.

It bothers me that the tool remarks on it, because it feels like smarter people than me have put in the message there. However, turning it off isn't an option because that'd turn off even the checks for actually unnecessarily declared variables.

Should I refactor the code? How can I improve it?

Comment: You should consider using more helpful error messages.

Comment: Check whether you pasted your real code correctly. Did you mean for the `id` parameter to be `userId`? Also, the question title should describe the task performed by the code (e.g. "Function to validate a GUID, an EntityState, and some data"). Alternatively, if you are asking a "What is best practice?" question about hypothetical/generic code rather than real concrete code, then it's not a Code Review, and would be better suited for [programmers.se]. I think that your question could use a bit more contextual information about what these parameters represent and where their values come from.

Comment: @200_success I'm not sure if the title now corresponds to my question. It rather reflects the answers, hehe. I mean to ask if it's OK to have the variables for validating only. I wouldn't ask, being sure it's fine, except R# has nagged about it, so I got curious if it's just being whiney or if I should be educated on a different syntax. (Unintentionally, I got some tips on improving the exception delivery, so it's even more great!)

Comment: If you're asking a "What is best practice in these generic situations?" question, then it's not a question for Code Review. Shall we restore your original title and migrate it to [programmers.se]?

Comment: @200_success I seem not to get through with it being **actual production** code. It's not a generic example. Would you like to see a screenshot from VS? Not sure what to do here...

Comment: The question can remain on Code Review as is. However, it takes some imagination to figure out what you are trying to accomplish with this code. It could be improved if you added more code or information so that we can see _why_ this function exists. What is `EntityState`? What is `data`? The contextual information would help us give you better advice, because there isn't much to work with.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Heslacher Oh, this one: "*should not append your revised code *" was new to me. I understand the point. In this particular case, I got so much feedback that I believed that in was in place to do a v2.0 of it. But rules are rules, even if blunt on occasion. I guess I should ask a new question (**veeery** alike) and delete this one.

Comment: Why do you want to delete this question ? You can just ask a follow up and leave this one.

Comment: @Heslacher Also - a **huuuge** thumbs up for the hint on why the rollback. THe first impression was *what the duck?!* (typo intended). THen I saw it. Very helpful and polite.

Comment: Thats my style ;-)

Comment: @Heslacher Hmmm... I felt that asking a new question that is so closely related to this one would lead to annoyance, impression of me being naggy and dupe stamp. I also have other points but that's for Meta.

Comment: Follow up questions are usually well received if they don't happen to come too fast. Duplicates on Code Review are hard to find because mostly the follow up questions contain significally changed code.

Answer (score 6):

It makes sense to use these arguments and throw `ArgumentException` or `ArgumentNullException` instead of just `Exception`:

```
private static void Validate(Guid userId, EntityState state, object data)
{
    if (userId == Guid.Empty)
        throw new ArgumentException("Token unrecognized!", nameof(userId));
    if (state == EntityState.Detached)
        throw new ArgumentException("Action unrecognized!", nameof(state));
    if (data == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data), "Data unrecognized!");
}
```

*Since the `nameof()` is a C#6 feature, in the previous versions of C# you should use argument name string instead: `"userId"`, `"state"`, `"data"`.*

Answer (score 2):

Besides `Dmitry`'s suggestion and based on `EBrown`'s comment, it makes sense to log more detailed information. This can be provided using a formatted exception string or using a logging library.

The second option has the advantage that can be customized to log only some levels (e.g. one usually wants less verbosity on production). The code using [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) (but this can be replaced with any other library or a custom one) would look like this:

```
private static void Validate(Guid userId, EntityState state, object data)
{
    String errorFormat = "{0} for user {1}, entity state {2}, object data = {3}";

    if (userId == Guid.Empty)
    {
        logger.Error(errorFormat, "Token unrecognized!", userId, state, data);
        throw new ArgumentException("Token unrecognized!", nameof(userId));
    }    

    if (state == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        logger.Error(errorFormat, "Action unrecognized!", userId, state, data);
        throw new ArgumentException("Action unrecognized!", nameof(state));
    }

    if (data == null)
    {
        logger.Error(errorFormat, "Data unrecognized!", userId, state, data);
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data), "Data unrecognized!");
    }
}
```